# Is this safe? (pointers to Objective C instance variables )

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers, instance-variables

I have some C functions that need access Instance variables. I already pass a struct in as an argument to the function, so I added pointers to the ivars to the struct.

Is it safe to rely on the pointer remaining valid throughout the life of the app (assuming i retain and release sensibly?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer remains valid as long as the thing it points to remains valid. If the object that contains the ivars gets dealloced, and someone else is still trying to use a pointer to one of the ivars, then yeah, it'll blow up.

That said, it might be a better design to just get and set the actual values as necessary; surely the ivars aren't so big that you *need* to point directly to them. Doing so breaks all notion of encapsulation and requires you to do a lot more error-prone work to make sure all your object lifetimes coincide. Feel free to say more or ask another question if you want more broad design advice.

Comment: Thank you, I think I really need to figure out good OO design with regards to Objective-C and C. I think i get the basics of it in Obj-C, but mixing ing structs and C functions blurring it for me.  I need to work in a render callback. The callback receives a struct and then i call a C function with info from that struct. I need ivar values in the method called from within the callback. fun fun fun

Comment: @griotspeak: So why not pass through a reference to the actual Obj-C object, and pull out the properties you care about when you call the inner C function? (Or if the values don't need to be updated, pull out all the values in advance and add them to the struct the ends up in the callback? Pointing to directly to some object's private ivars in some asynchronous callback is super fragile.

Comment: I can't make obj-C calls in the callback. that would take too long and i would get an audio glitch. my thinking behind adding pointers to the ivar instead of the value is that there are 2 structs involved and i could just update the ivar. I am between this and just passing the values. Thanks again